# Call value from dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am building a model that requires different input values according to the type of building. I have a data frame with the data of the buildings. In a simplified form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[ 'House', 0.17, 0.3], 
[ 'Hotel', 0.43, 0.23], 
[ 'Restaruant', 0.61, 0.34], 
[ 'Office', 0.49, 0.12], 
[ 'School', 0.37, 0.53]], columns=('Building', 'Probability 1', 'Probability 2'))
```

In another script I have the input values for the building so that the return value is linked to the building chosen. I need to use the Probability 1 value in the above dataframe in another script.

How can I look for the input value in the dataframe and use that probability in another script?

Eg. return the Probability 1 of an Office building.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand it correctly. But assuming you want the Probability 1 column and the buildingtype is a variable. Then this would suffice I guess.

```
building = 'Office'
df[df.Building==building]['Probability 1'].values[0]
```

Look where the values of the Building column are equal to the building parameter. Then we only need the column 'Probability 1', use values. This returns an array of length 1. Here we need the first element (only element).

Answer (score 0):

Convert `Building` column to index, so possible use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for selecting:

```
df = df.set_index('Building')

out = df.loc['Office','Probability 1']
```